# Infopath 2007 Deployment-Error

Tags: infopath

I am trying to publish an Infopath form 2007 without code behind concept by using the publish option from file menu and comes up with the following error.

The selected form template cannot be overwritten with the active form template. To Publish the active Template, publish it to a different location?

This is happening in step no 4 of the wizard.

Any Suggestion please? If you need more info, please ask!

Thank you

Comment: Do you have the flexibility to redeploy this form or is it being currently used in production?

Comment: Yes I do.but during the publishing wizard,  Step number 3, When I click on checkbox Enable this form to be filled out by using browser, Document Library and Site Content Type(advanced ) are greyed out. I don't know why?  Its asking for the location and filename for the form template. I seriously need some help in here. Thank you

Comment: Are you logged in as the Site Collection Administrator? Also I assume you are trying to publish to a SharePoint 2007 server?

Comment: Can you please tell me if you are logged in as Site Collection Administrator?

Comment: This is a question about InfoPath. As requested previously, please keep your questions on topic. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

Tools > Form Options > Programming > Remove Code

if you at some point accidentaly created a code behind and never used it.

Make sure you are logged in as Site Collection Admin if you want to publilsh the form as a Site Content Type, which is by the way my preferred method for browser based forms.

Comment: Its already greyed out. Thank you.So, I am still wiating for the solution

Comment: Thanks Karthik, I have found  a solution to this,which I would like to share, but it is not efficient though. I have to create a new site and publish the form in the new site. It looks like there is kind of a conflict for the form already existed in the site , So still looking for the correct solution. Thanks again